# 複数条件の抽出方法

Tags: python, pandas

- 1月1日を抽出したい場合

  ```
  df = df.query('日付＋エリア.str.contains("1月1日")')
  ```
- 1月1日の東京を抽出したい場合

  ```
  df = df.query('日付＋エリア.str.contains("1月1日.+東京")')
  ```

もし1月1日の東京と神奈川を抽出したい場合、どのようなコードを書けば良いでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 要件から若干ずれますが、`str.contains`では11月1日もヒットするため`str.match`にするほうが適切かと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
dfx = df[df['日付＋エリア'].str.contains(r'^1月1日＿(?:東京|神奈川)＿')]
print(dfx)
```

| 種類 | 日付＋エリア |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1月1日＿東京＿新宿 |
| 1 | 1月1日＿東京＿八王子 |
| 1 | 1月1日＿神奈川＿横浜 |
| 1 | 1月1日＿神奈川＿藤沢 |

**追記**

> もし"日付とエリア"に変更したら、

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    '種類': [1] * 18,
    '日付とエリア': [
        '1月1日＿東京＿新宿', '1月2日＿東京＿新宿', '1月3日＿東京＿新宿',
        '1月1日＿東京＿八王子', '1月2日＿東京＿八王子', '1月3日＿東京＿八王子',
        '1月1日＿神奈川＿横浜', '1月2日＿神奈川＿横浜', '1月3日＿神奈川＿横浜',
        '1月1日＿神奈川＿藤沢', '1月2日＿神奈川＿藤沢', '1月3日＿神奈川＿藤沢',
        '1月1日＿千葉＿千葉', '1月2日＿千葉＿千葉', '1月3日＿千葉＿千葉',
        '1月1日＿千葉＿市川', '1月2日＿千葉＿市川', '1月3日＿千葉＿市川',
    ],
})

dfx = df.query('日付とエリア.str.contains(r"^1月1日＿(?:東京|神奈川)＿")')
print(dfx)

#    種類          日付とエリア
# 0     1    1月1日＿東京＿新宿
# 3     1  1月1日＿東京＿八王子
# 6     1  1月1日＿神奈川＿横浜
# 9     1  1月1日＿神奈川＿藤沢
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。queryで使えますか？

Comment: 手元の Pandas は 1.5.3 なのですが、カラム名に `＋` が入っているので query ではエラーになってしまいます。(バックティックで囲んでもエラー)

Comment: もし"日付とエリア"に変更したら、これでqueryも使えないんですか？

Comment: はい、それでしたら問題ありません。`df.query('日付とエリア.str.contains(r"1月1日＿(?:東京|神奈川)＿")')`

Comment: ありがとうございました。失礼しますが、df.query('日付とエリア.str.contains(r"1月1日＿(?:東京|神奈川)＿")')で実行したら、Empty DataFrameになってしまいました。

Comment: こちらでの実行状況を追記してみました。そちらの環境でも実行してみてください。